# Debugging custom CordovaPlugin

Tags: android, cordova

This is my first question here.

I am using Cordova 3.4.0-0.1.3 and would like to write a custom Android plugin. After some tutorials, I have managed to  call my custom plugin from my Cordova app by executing "cordova run android" command. The app starts and with my remote debug console I can see my own "Hello world" message from my own Cordova plugin.
The next thing I would like to do is debugging my plugin in Eclipse.

The first thing I tried was to launch the app from Eclipse by executing the AndroidManifest.xml located in the /cordovaproject/platforms/android/ folder. 
After the app was launched, the following javascript errors i get in my remote console:

```
deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds. cordova.js:1128
Channel not fired: onNativeReady cordova.js:1121
Channel not fired: onPluginsReady cordova.js:1121
Channel not fired: onCordovaReady cordova.js:1121
```

It look likes there are Cordova components that aren't loading when you directly run the app in Eclipse.

This error does not occur when I deploy the app with "cordova run android".

My question is:
How can I properly run/debug my Cordova plugin in Eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed my problem. The problem was that I added the android plugin by "Import existing project".

The correct way to add the Cordova android project in Eclipse is to create an new "Android Application project" with existing sources.
When you do this, the referenced CordovaLib project is also found by Eclipse.